# Problem with WPF Toolkit Calendar invoked from DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, calendar, datatemplate, toolkit

I'm noticing a serious issue with WPF Toolkit Calendar control.  It works fine if I just invoke it with normal inline XAML and set the DisplayDate to a date string, like this:

```
<toolkit:Calendar DisplayDate="12/6/2010"/>
```

However, it never honors the DisplayDate parameter when I use a DataTemplate to cause the Calendar to display.  Here's an example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Dashboard.Presentation.View.CalendarView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <toolkit:Calendar DisplayDate="{Binding Path=.}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <sys:DateTime>11/1/2010</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>12/1/2010</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>1/1/2011</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>2/1/2011</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>3/1/2011</sys:DateTime>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

I have added a TextBlock to the DataTemplate so you can see that the Date is being bound properly, it is just not honored by the Calendar.

Is this a bug in WPF Toolkit Calendar?  If so how can I get this fixed?  Or is this something I'm doing wrong with DataTemplates?

Comment: Note to stackoverflow admin: My post includes </UserControl> at the bottom of my second code block, but the stackoverflow website does not render that closing tag.

Comment: I should have mentioned my version. This is .Net framework 3.5 with WPF Toolkit version v3.5.50211.1 (aka February 2010 release). Using .Net framework 4.0 is not an option for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with the calendar control.It resets the DisplayDate of the contol in a datatemplate somewhere before the loaded event.Any way Resetting it in the Loaded event seems to do the trick.Try this

```
private void Calendar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

  {

      ((Calendar)sender).DisplayDate = (DateTime) ((Calendar)sender).DataContext;

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for verifying that it's a bug.  Your workaround is simple and works fine for me.